# Probability of cross-free path

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I don't know how to name such problem, but basically we have an infinite two dimensional grid with mouse (point, machine, whatever) that moves up, down, left or right. Every move has same probability 25%. What is the probability, that no place was visited more than once after 'n' moves?

Comment: Try searching for "self-intersecting random walk".